# Increase the font size for R script file in RGUI in windows

Tags: r, windows

Any idea how to increase the font size for R script file in RGUI in windows?

I know how to do it for the console i.e. go to edit -> GUI preferences and then edit font size or through the environment file.

I need to do it for the script editor.

By the way, I don`t want to use RStudio for some reason and need a solution for this in windows, for mac, I know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the same as you did for the console, then open a new script. The font size should be the same as the console now.